# How to keep inline with echo

Tags: magento-1.7, php

How to keep this code result on single line (no split). The result is displayed on a table and the column width is splitting the result in two lines. How to keep the output on single line? How to use the echo to fix that problem?
Thank you!

```
$price = sprintf("%0.2f", $price); 

$parts = explode('.', $price);

echo "$parts[0] <span style = 'font-color: #ff0000; font-size:12px'><sup> ,$parts[1] USD</sup></span>";
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change size of a column on Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/how-to-change-size-of-a-column-on-magento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent wrapping of text by using the white-space property in css:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Problem fixed:  echo "$parts[0]<span style = 'white-space: nowrap; font-color: #ff0000;font-size:12px'><sup> ,$parts[1] USD</sup></span>";

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of inline styles like this but you could try adding a `width` to it.

```
echo "<span style='width:120px'>$parts[0] <span style = 'font-color: #ff0000; font-size:12px;'><sup> ,$parts[1] USD</sup></span></span>";
```

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: @Ben Robie's answer is correct.